# Message: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException : Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression

Tags: c#, oledbconnection

```
public static void WriteData(string colName,string data)
{
    using (OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + Constants.FileName + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=3;READONLY=FALSE\""))
    {
        // string query = String.Format("INSERT INTO  [DataSet$]({0}) VALUES ({1})",colName, data);

        string query = String.Format("INSERT INTO  [DataSet$]({0}) VALUES ({1})", colName, data);
        cn.Open();
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, cn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@colName", colName);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data", data);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cn.Close();
        cn.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking, but please note that the code as it is is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: I am not able to insert data into sheet and it is throwing the above exception.

Comment: I am new to c# and sql . Could any one please help with the above syntax error??

Comment: Can you debug the code and check what value is being assigned to `query` and share it here? What values are assigned to `colName` and `data` variables?

Comment: Did you really name your table "DataSet$"?  Give it a real name, without any symbols.  Your Insert query makes little sense:  you are trying to insert one piece of data into one of potential many columns?

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is mixing dynamic query generation and queryparameters.
You can not use command parameters to populate column names in the query. Parameters are used only for passing values to the query.

So what you need to do is, to use `string.Format` only for placing column name in the query and use command parameter only to pass data to the query.

```
public void WriteData(string colName, string data)
{
    using (OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + Constants.FileName + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=3;READONLY=FALSE\""))
    {
        string query = string.Format("INSERT INTO [DataSet$] ({0}) VALUES (@data)", colName);
        // The query variable will have following value assuming colName=token
        //INSERT INTO [DataSet$] (token) VALUES (@data)
        cn.Open();
        //Now use OleDbCommand to pass value of @data to the query.
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, cn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data", data);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cn.Close();
    }
}
```

This should help you resolve your issue.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply Chetan . Could you please let me know how to update the table too??

Comment: which takes rowname ,colname and data to be inserted.

Comment: What is rowname here? You have multiple columns to update? Have you already tried some code for that? Did this solution worked for INSERT operation?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void UpdateData(string keyName,string colName,string data)
    {
        using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + Constants.FileName + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=3;READONLY=FALSE\""))
        {
            // string query = String.Format("INSERT INTO  [DataSet$]({0}) VALUES ({1})",colName, data);

                connection.Open();
                string commandString = String.Format("UPDATE [DataSet$] SET colName ='{0}' WHERE keyName = '{1}'",@data,@keyName);
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(commandString, connection);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data", data);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@keyName", keyName);
            connection.Close();
                connection.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to follow the same.approach as my answer. Use string.format to fill in the column names and command parameters to fill the values.

Comment: What is the keyname here? It's a column name? Then you need to have value also for that. Can you explain the use case for which you needs to do this? This code of your has the same problem as your first code.

Comment: Can you share the sample values of keyname, colname and data?

Comment: I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Link-only answers are difficult to understand and are likely to suffer from link-rot issues. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can reproduce most relevant portion of the link in the post itself.